# Как разбить строку имея несколько разделителей

Tags: javascript, split

Имею строку к примеру в виде `result = "2.3-54+2*8"`.

Как я смогу используя всего один split() получить массив состоящий только из цифр?

Посидев на сайте и поискав инфу способ по типу `result.split(/"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"/)` как бы должен работать но в моем случае - мимо. Если убрать кавычки в каждом операторе, JS прокидывает ошибку.

Comment: Убрать кавычки и заэкранировать деление. Но основы я зыка всё же надо знать, что бы не писать глупых синтаксических ошибок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Символы `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` в регулярных выражениях являются специальными, поэтому их нужно экранировать.

Кавычки действительно не нужны:

```js
var result = "2.3-54+2*8";

console.log(result.split(/\+|\-|\*|\//))
```

Если сами разделители тоже нужны, нужно обернуть их в группу `()`

```js
var result = "2.3-54+2*8";

console.log(result.split(/(\+|\-|\*|\/)/))
```

Comment: Я б квадратные скобки использовал `[+\-*\/]`. Не помню, нужно ли там экранировать слеш

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в квадратных, по идее, только минус нужно экранировать, если он не последним идет